# Secure connections between client, load balancer and server

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The past week or so I have been getting to grips with the world of AWS and more specifically Elastic Beanstalk and Load Balancing...

The application I'm developing enforces a SSL/HTTPS connection using a custom RequireHttps attribute I'm applying globally. I initially had problems configuring the load balancer with this set up, but it does appear to be working as expected.

My problem originates from [a blog post](http://blog.dontpaniclabs.com/post/2012/12/19/Redirecting-to-HTTPS-while-using-Amazons-Elastic-Load-Balancer.aspx) I was glancing over around the time I was setting up the Load Balancer/RequireHttps attribute. Quoting this blog post:

> When using Elastic Beanstalk ... the connection between the load balancer and application server is not secure. However, **you don't need to be concerned with the security of the connection between the load balancer and the server** but you do need to be concerned about the connection between the client and the load balancer.

As configuring load balancers is an entirely new area for me, I'm a little sceptical that the above is entirely true.

Is the connection between a load balancer and server truly none of my concern? Would it be better to *not* terminate SSL at the Load Balancer and pass a sercure connection straight through to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little further research, I stumbled across the following post/discussion on security.stackexchange: [Should SSL be terminated at a load balancer?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30403/should-ssl-be-terminated-at-a-load-balancer)

> makerofthings7:
>
> It seems to me the question is "do you trust your own datacenter". In other words, it seems like you're trying to finely draw the line where the untrusted networks lie, and the trust begins.
>
> **In my opinion, SSL/TLS trust should terminate at the SSL offloading device since the department that manages that device often also manages the networking and infrastructure. There is a certain amount of contractual trust there.** There is no point of encrypting data at a downstream server since the same people who are supporting the network usually have access to this as well. (with the possible exception in multi-tenant environments, or unique business requirements that require deeper segmentation).
>
> A second reason SSL should terminate at the load balancer is because it offers a centralized place to correct SSL attacks such as CRIME or BEAST. If SSL is terminated at a variety of web servers, running on different OS's you're more likely to run into problems due to the additional complexity . Keep it simple, and you'll have fewer problems in the long run.

I can see that what @makerofthings7 is saying makes sense. Whether SSL is terminated at the Load Balancer or Server should make little difference.